# Is there any Eloquent way to get sum of relational table and sort by it?

Tags: sql, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-5.6

Example:

table Users

```
ID | Username | sex
1  | Tony     | m
2  | Andy     | m
3  | Lucy     | f
```

table Scores

```
ID | user_id | score
1  | 2       | 4
2  | 1       | 3
3  | 1       | 4
4  | 2       | 3
5  | 1       | 1
6  | 3       | 3
7  | 3       | 2
8  | 2       | 3
```

Expected Result:

```
ID | Username | sex | score_sum (sum) (desc)
2  | Andy     | m   | 10
1  | Tony     | m   | 8
3  | Lucy     | f   | 5
```

The code I use so far:

User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...
    public function scores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Score');
    }
    ...
}
```

Score model

```
class Job extends Model
{
   //i put nothing here
}
```

Code in controller:

```
$users = User::all();

foreach ($users as $user){
    $user->score_sum = $user->scores()->sum('score');
}

$users = collect($users)->sortByDesc('score_sum'); 
return view('homepage', [
    'users' => $users->values()->all()
]);
```

Hope my example above make sense. My code does work, but I thought there must be an Eloquent and elegant way to do this without `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options for doing this in an Eloquent way.

**Option 1**

The first way is to do this to add the `score_sum` as an attribute that is always included when querying the `users` model. This is only a good idea if you will be using the `score_sum` the majority of the time when querying the `users` table. If you only need the `score_sum` on very specific view or for specific business logic then I would use the second option below.

To do this you will add the attribute to the `users` model, you can look here for documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Here is an example for your use case:

**/app/User.php**

```
class User extends Model
{
    .
    .
    .
    public function getScoreSumAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->scores()->sum('score');
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

If you just want to do this for a single use case, then the easiest solution is just to use the `sum()` function in the eventual `foreach` loop you will be using (most likely in the view).

For example in a view:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <div>Username: {{$user->username}}</div>
    <div>Sex: {{$user->sex}}</div>
    <div>Score Sum: {{$user->scores()->sum('price')}}</div>
@endforeach
```

Additionally, if you do not want to do this in a `foreach` loop you can use a raw query in the Eloquent call in your Controller gets the `score_sum'. Here is an example of how that can be done:

```
$users = User::select('score_sum',DB::raw(SUM(score) FROM 'scores'))->get();
```

*I did not have a quick environment to test this, you might need a WHERE clause in the `DB::raw` query*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes. This is elegant at least for me.

Comment: This is elegant, but can it sort by the sum?

Answer (score 1):

This is as nice as it gets:

```
User::selectRaw('*, (SELECT SUM(score) FROM scores WHERE user_id = users.id) as score_sum')
    ->orderBy('score_sum', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I mean without sql queries too.

Comment: Eloquent doesn't implement a way to do this. This is the most performant way. If you use the accessor from the other answer you have a `n + 1` problem since every time you call `$user->score_sum` you execute another query.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs, your code is good too. The code I worked on actually for small number of records.